# What are the possible causes of error 14000, "Fail to start messaging", in the SendBird iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, instant-messaging, sendbird

I'm trying to use the SendBird SDK to implement a simple instant messaging feature in my iOS app.

I've read the Quick Start, Authentication, and Messaging Channel - Basic guides, and I've attempted to set up a 1-1 messaging channel as they describe.

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I included `SendBird.initAppId("MyAppID")`.

In my initial view controller, I log in the user. I'm using the user's username from my app as his userId, and I'm concatenating his first and last name to use as his SendBird nickname:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if let emailAddress = KCSUser.activeUser().email,
        firstName = KCSUser.activeUser().givenName,
        lastName = KCSUser.activeUser().surname {

        let nickname = firstName.lowercaseString + lastName.lowercaseString
        SendBird.loginWithUserId(emailAddress, andUserName: nickname)
    }
}
```

Finally, in the actual chat view controller, I attempt to start a messaging channel with another user:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    guard let targetId = session?.parent?.user?.email else {
        return
    }

    // I logged in once with this id, so according to the SendBird docs, the
    // user should exist.
    SendBird.startMessagingWithUserId(targetId)

    SendBird.setEventHandlerConnectBlock({ (channel) in
        NSLog("%@", channel)
    }, errorBlock: { (errorCode) in
        NSLog("%D", errorCode)
    }, channelLeftBlock: { (channel) in

    }, messageReceivedBlock: { (message) in

    }, systemMessageReceivedBlock: { (systemMessage) in

    }, broadcastMessageReceivedBlock: { (broadcastMessage) in

    }, fileReceivedBlock: { (fileLink) in

    }, messagingStartedBlock: { (messagingChannel) in
        SendBird.joinChannel(messagingChannel.getUrl())

        // SendBirdChannelInfo is a custom struct for some use within the app
        let channelInfo = SendBirdChannelInfo(
            channelId: messagingChannel.getId(),
            url: messagingChannel.getUrl()
        )

        // self.session is a custom data model for use with our database.
        self.session?.sendBirdChannelInfo = channelInfo

        SendBird.queryMessageListInChannel(messagingChannel.getUrl()).prevWithMessageTs(
            Int64.max, andLimit: 30, resultBlock: { (queryResult) in

            var maxMessageTs = Int64.min

            for model in queryResult {
                if maxMessageTs <= (model as! SendBirdMessageModel).getMessageTimestamp() {
                    maxMessageTs = (model as! SendBirdMessageModel).getMessageTimestamp()
                }
            }

            SendBird.connectWithMessageTs(maxMessageTs)
        }, endBlock: { (error) in
            if let fetchMessagesError = error {
                NSLog(fetchMessagesError.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }, messagingUpdatedBlock: { (messagingChannel) in

    }, messagingEndedBlock: { (messagingChannel) in

    }, allMessagingEndedBlock: { 

    }, messagingHiddenBlock: { (messagingChannel) in

    }, allMessagingHiddenBlock: { 

    }, readReceivedBlock: { (readStatus) in

    }, typeStartReceivedBlock: { (typeStatus) in

    }, typeEndReceivedBlock: { (typeStatus) in

    }, allDataReceivedBlock: { (unsignedInt, thirtyTwoBitInt) in

    }, messageDeliveryBlock: { (sent, message, data, messageId) in

    }, mutedMessagesReceivedBlock: { (message) in

    }) { (fileLink) in

    }
}
```

With the exception of the lines I commented, this code comes directly from the SendBird manual. However, when it runs, I receive error code 14000, and the message, "Fail to start messaging," is logged.

What is the actual cause of the error? Am I missing a step during user login or SDK initialization, or is there another step in creating a channel? Or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Have you ever logged in with the `targetId`?

Comment: When I asked this question, yes, I had logged in with the targetId. However, I had not logged in either user with a token. I decided to try logging in the users with tokens, though I had Non-Access Token User Policy set to Read & Write, and then the users were able to send and receive messages.

Answer (score 1):

Please try our new SDK instead of the old SDK which will be deprecated soon!

https://docs.sendbird.com/ios

Thanks!